# How to break an int into digits and assign digits to a vector in same order?

Tags: c++, loops, vector, bit

I am using a Constructor to take an `unsigned int` as an argument, break it into digits and assign the appropriate `true` and `false` values to a `vector` object. But the problem is that, my poor logic assigns the values in reverse order as the last digit is separated first and so on. The Code I have written is:

```
vector<bool> _bits; 
uBinary(unsigned int num){  
    int i = 1;
    while(num > 0)
    {
        int d = num%10;
        num /= 10;
        _bits.resize(i++);
        if(d == 1)
        {
            _bits[_bits.size() - 1] = true; 
        }
        else if(d==0)
        {
            _bits[_bits.size() - 1] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

For example: if argument 10011 is passed to the function `uBinary()` the vector object will be assigned the values in this order `11001` or `true,true,false,false,true` which is reversed. 
All I need to do here is that, I want to assign the values without reversing the order and I don't want to use another loop for this purpose.

Comment: why do you use a `unsigned int` to store a binary in the first place?

Comment: cheat and use a `std::bitset` :)

Comment: you can `std::reverse` a `vector`, though not sure if it works with a `vector<bool>`

Comment: @tobi303 actually I am using bool to store bits. unsigned int is only passed as argument there

Comment: If you want to do it without reversing at the end (which is by far the simplest way), you need to know the number of digits in advance, which requires a loop or call to `log10`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I appreciate your idea, but I am a beginner and want to develop good logic, that's why i am doing this to practice my programming skills

Comment: @Cameron thanks Sir ... I don't want to use another loop. But will check that log10 method. Thanks for adding something new to my knowledge :)

Comment: imho `_bits.back()` is nicer to read than `_bits.[_bits.size()-1]` and if anyhow you increase the size for each element you could as well use `push_back` instead of `resize` + assign

Comment: Wait, why is your input in decimal? Why not either a string or the actual bits themselves in a `uint32_t` or something?

Comment: Thanks @tobi303 I really know the difference. push_back() will be better here. But I was thinking of assigning the elements in reverse order to overcome this problem that's why used this one

Comment: @Cameron what if the user enters the input? That's why I used unisgned int. I know I am wrong in many places. But as i mentioned, im just a beginner and in learning process. Thanks for all your kind advises :)

Comment: I would suggest you to use a `std::string` for the input, however, maybe then the task is to easy to make a good excercise ;)

Comment: If the user enters the input, it will be a string of characters (which is more efficient to process than all these integer divisions...).

Comment: Instead of `_bits[_bits.size()-1]= true`, you might currently use `_bits.push_back(true)`, and to have in reverse order, `_bits.insert(_bits.begin(), true)`. but `reverse` at the end is simpler and more efficient (as push_front for vector is `O(N)`).

Comment: at least you should `reserve` some space in the vector to avoid frequent reallocations when you `resize` or `push_back`

Comment: Okay guys... Thanks a lot all of you. I have learnt new things from you. :) 
And will have a look  on all of these ideas. Thanks ! :)

Comment: @Jarod42 Sir your Idea is awesome. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Now I know how to handle such problems with vectors. And yes, will be using string instead of integers to take such input. Thanks Again

Answer (score 2):

One way is to start at the highest possible digit (`unsigned int` can only hold values up to 4294967295 on most platforms) and ignore leading zeros until the first actual digit is found:

```
for (uint32_t divisor = 1000000000; divisor != 0; divisor /= 10) {
    uint32_t digit = num / divisor % 10;
    if (digit == 0 && _bits.size() == 0 && divisor != 1)
        continue;  // ignore leading zeros
    _bits.push_back(digit == 1);
}
```

But finding the digits in reverse and then simply reversing them is much simpler (and at least as efficient):

```
do {
    _bits.push_back(num % 10 == 1);
    num /= 10;
} while (num != 0);
std::reverse(_bits.begin(), _bits.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do the reversing with another loop or `std::reverse` is to use recursion.  With recursion you can walk down the int until you hit the last digit and then you add the values to the vector as the calls return.  That would look like

```
void uBinary(unsigned int num)
{   
    if (num == 0)
        return;
    uBinary(num / 10);
    _bits.push_back(num % 10 ? true : false);
}
```

Which you can see working with

```
int main()
{
    uBinary(10110);
    for (auto e : _bits)
        std::cout << e << " ";
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8ce6f2876105453)</kbd>

---

Do note that it is advisable not to use leading underscores in variables names.  Some names are reserved for the implementation and if you use one it is undefined behavior.  For a full explanation of underscores in names see: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: Nice solution, didn't think of recursion :-) It doesn't handle when there's only one 0 digit, though.

Comment: Thanks . Nice one... But wouldn't it have a greater time complexity?

Comment: @HNLearner It should be O(N).  What it does have is call stack overhead but that is pretty minimal overhead as the recursion depth is not too deep.

Comment: Okay Sir got that. I didn't think of recursion. This is also a good one. :)

Comment: @Cameron Good point.  Not sure how I could get zero to work with this.  I'll have to think about it.

Comment: @NathanOliver Consider renaming `_bits` to something like `bits`. Some people might actually think that it is a valid name (even if it actually is) and use it somewhere else (where it isn't).

Comment: @Rakete1111 I'm just using what the OP has.  AFAIK `_bits` is a valid name in C++

Comment: @NathanOliver I know, but a simple change like `_Bits` renders it invalid. But ok :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 Added a bit to the answer to let the OP know about it.